# Curve matching in Java

Tags: java, opencv, matching, curve

First question here so sorry if anything I ask is completely stupid.

I'm working in a shape recognition project where it is supposed for me to develop an application that receives two images: an original one and a sketch made by a user. I am supposed to detect contours of the two images and find the best match in the original image corresponding to the sketch made by the user.

I am already learning some basics about the Canny edge detection and was able to get the contours of several images. After having the contours, I need to analyze all contours in the image and find the best match, disregarding translation, rotation, scaling and occlusion.

Then, I found this code that does exactly what I want: 
http://www.morethantechnical.com/2012/12/27/2d-curve-matching-in-opencv-w-code/ but is in C++.

Do you know any alternative for similar code in Java or any algorithm that could be useful to me? I also discovered BoofCV but it seems that such task is not implemented.

Thank you for your patience.

EDIT:

I've been searching for other ways of doing this, and I found the Hausdorff distance:
http://cgm.cs.mcgill.ca/~godfried/teaching/cg-projects/98/normand/main.html

Is it possible to modify this algorithm to be rotation invariant? They only talk about translation and scaling.

Comment: start small and humble: http://docs.opencv.org/java/org/opencv/imgproc/Imgproc.html#matchShapes(org.opencv.core.Mat,%20org.opencv.core.Mat,%20int,%20double)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion :) I tried using findContours and matchShapes from OpenCV but the results weren't good. The Hu moments say that a small rectangle is the most similar to a contour of a plane...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mentioned you already have the source code in C++ and can't find a Java version - possibly your best bet might be to convert the C++ code into Java code. If you don't need all parts of the C++ program, you might want to covert only the parts (classes) that you need.

Conversion from C++ to Java might not be always trivial but I am guessing it might be easier if you know exactly what you want and how you want your program to behave. Below is a link to some conversion tools - although they might not be free.

http://www.researchgate.net/post/How_to_convert_the_C_C_code_to_java2

Comment: I'm going to accept your answer as you were the only one answering. I wasn't able to convert the code, so I decided to implement an algorithm from a paper regarding this subject.